# Linear equation with one unknown using Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, constraint-programming

I am wondering how to solve basic linear equation with one unknown.

I tried doing it by string splitting in order to get everything i need to solve the equation, but i am sure there is a better way.

```
solve(5 + X = 10).
X = 5.
solve(5+8 = Ans).
Ans = 13.
```

This is the thing I'm trying to solve. I want to use solve/1.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solve(X+Y=Z):-X+Y#=Z.
```

Some examples:

```
?- solve(5+X=10).
X = 5.

?- solve(5+8=ANS).
ANS = 13.
```

To solve it without libraries you could write:

```
solve(S):-var(S),throw("instatiation error").
solve(X+Y=Z):-(var(X),var(Y);var(X),var(Z);
               var(Y),var(Z)),throw("instatiation error").
solve(X+Y=Z):-nonvar(Z),nonvar(Y),L is Z-Y,X=L.
solve(X+Y=Z):-nonvar(Z),nonvar(X),L is Z-X,Y=L.
solve(X+Y=Z):-nonvar(X),nonvar(Y),L is X+Y,Z=L.
```

and again the examples:

```
?- solve(5+X=10).
X = 5 ;
false.

?- solve(5+8=Ans).
Ans = 13.
```

Comment: I mean it could work something like so

`solve(X+Y=Z):-
    X is Z - Y ;  Y is Z - X ;  Z is X + Y.`     

But i have no clue how to make it do the selection based on what has been given.
@coder

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps!!

Comment: It helps, Thanks!

Comment: Your new answer is wrong: `?- solve(E).` says **false**, although there are solutions. It is not easy to replace the functionality of a constraint solver with low-level code. I recommend to avoid it. Instead, it is better to tell instructors to upgrade their Prolog knowledge if they prevent you from using Prolog in Prolog courses.

Comment: I simply tried the most general query, which is always a good idea to find out more about a Prolog predicate: `?- solve(E).` asks: "Are there *any* solutions?" The predicate *incorrectly* says: "No, there aren't any."

Comment: It is not wrong, the first predicate I agree is much better because solve gives a solution: X = (_G543+_G544=_G541) and also works for solve1(X+Y=2).  with output X+Y#=2.The second predicate clearly fails in both inputs because it is forced to have only one variable at a time so it could solve right an equation X+Y=Z with only one variable as it was asked in the first comment above. I would prefer first solve/1 but for solving an equation the second solve/1 is also working....

Comment: Answering with `false` means that there are *no solutions* whatsoever. It is therefore a *wrong* answer to say `false` if there are solutions! In such cases, you *must* throw an **instantiation error** to indicate that the predicate cannot state a better answer, if you want to make reasoning about your program in a logical way possible at all. There are also other shortcomings. For example `?- X+Y#=X.` deduces `Y=0`. Your second `solve/1` does not.

Comment: I agree, but this is due to nonvar/1. Every predicate conatining nonvar/1 it is clear that can't work reversible because it only succeeds with constant and not with variable . The second predicate is less efficient due to nonvar and succeeds when provided two constant and a variable in the equasion...It can solve only these type equations.

Comment: Yes, that's due to `nonvar/1`! You should add `var/1` test and throw an *instantiation error* if the arguments are not sufficiently instantiated to give a sound answer. Otherwise, the program will not behave as we expect from a relation.

Comment: Ok I get it thanks!!! I updated my answer throwing exceptions in these cases. Do you think now is ok? are here any other input that I should consider??

Comment: That's definitely a lot better! Thank you for updating this! Remaining cases that would be interesting are those where the predicate currently throws an instantiation error, but in fact has enough information to produce a solution, such as `solve(X + Y = X)` or `solve(A + B = B)`. In such cases, it is clear that `Y` and `A` must be *zero*. The CLP(FD) version is able to deduce this! Other than that, I would point to GNU Prolog and B-Prolog, where CLP(FD) constraints are available as built-ins without the need to load any libraries. The more we use this, the sooner other systems will follow.

Comment: One more thing I tried to handle the exception for example by writting a predicate handle:-catch(solve(X),"instatiation error",write("wrong")). but how can this catch the exception when I call solve(X) for example??

Comment: An instantiation error has a well-defined form, please see the Prolog ISO standard and `library(error)` in SWI-Prolog for examples how to throw it. You can also try it with library CLP(FD), using for example `?- X in Var.` and catching the exception to see what it looks like. You should use the standardized version for throwing such an error. Also, one more point: Every time you have a unification like `X = L`, the question arises: Why did you even introduce `L` at all? Simply use `X` *instead*, since these are obviously identical.

Comment: I tried it now and both solve predicates return true...did you find any mistake??